# Equivalence of definitions of torsion of a curve

Tags: differential-geometry

The classical definition of torsion of a curve is $\tau(s)= -B´(s)\cdot N(s)$ where B is the binormal vector and N is the normal vector but I´ve seen another definition of torsion: $\tau=lim_{\Delta s\to 0} {\Delta \theta\over \Delta s}$ where $\Delta \theta$ is the angle between the osculating planes at two points adyacent to each other say $P(s)$ and $P(s+\Delta s)$

How can I prove the equivalence between this two definitions? I would really appreciate if you can give me a hand :)

Answer (score 0):

consider $\alpha(s)$ with $|\alpha'(s)|=1$, $B=$binormal, $s=0, \theta(0)=0$

$B(s)=B(0)+sB'(0)+\frac{s^2}{2}B''(0)+O(s^3)$

$\cos(\theta(s))=<B(s),B(0)>=1+\frac{s^2}{2}<B''(0),B(0)>+O(s^3)$

On the other hand,

$\cos(\theta(s))=1-s\sin(\theta(0))\theta'(0)+\frac{s^2}{2}(-sin(\theta(0))\theta''-cos(\theta(0))(\theta'(s))^2)+O(s^3)$

Compare 
$$-\frac{s^2}{2}\theta'(s))^2+O(s^3)=\frac{s^2}{2}<B''(0),B(0)>+O(s^3)=\frac{s^2}{2}<((-\tau N(s))''(0),B(0)>+O(s^3)=\frac{s^2}{2}-\tau^2(0)+O(s^3)$$

The last identity we need to use Frenet formula. Compare above two expressions, you get $|\tau(0)|=|\theta'(0)|$